# Data validation arrow does not show automatically

Tags: excel, validation

The **arrow box** next to all **data validation** fields in my xlsm file **does not show automatically** when clicking in the validation cell. It shows up quickly and disappears immediately. When clicking where the arrow box is supposed to be, the data validation options show up as usually and now the arrow box shows up permanently until I select and option.
*Any hints how to solve this? Thanks!*

[Check similar unsolved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833963/data-validation-drop-down-box-arrow-disappearing)

File>Options>Advanced>For objects, show: ALL is enabled (and doesn't change anything)

**open & repair** didn't solve the issue either

PD: I use VBA a lot in this workbook but none should access the dropdowns.

EDIT: I imported a sheet from a different workbook where the arrow is displayed normally and the same issue occurs.
EDIT2: On some worksheets the issue does not occur. By creating a new data validation field on such a sheet and going back to a corrupted sheet, the arrow box shows up perfectly...

Comment: Never seen this before, but my guess: do you have anything going on in `Worksheet_SelectionChanged` events?  Could be possible that an error in there is leaving something changed that affects the data validation.  Maybe an `On Error Resume Next` is hiding something relevant?  Only guesses though...

Comment: Thank you. I could not find such a function in my code. But I found a not-so-nice "workaround" to disable the bug (see EDIT2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this issue is only related to the speed of the Excel Sheet itself.
I had various **linked pictures** in the workbook that made it very slow, resulting as well in the data validation arrow issue.

Removing the linked pictures would improve the performance and resolve the issue.

(Previously I had a workaround that seemed to work sometimes: I could solve the issue by creating a macro in "ThisWorkbook" that goes on two sheets and selects the fields with data validation activated:

```
Sheet("1").Range("DataValidation1").Select
Sheet("2").Range("DataValidation2").Select
```

Strange enough, this was sufficient to solve the problem. )